# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) when timer calls a function

Tags: ios, swift

I got two problems, the first one is I'm getting the error message described above (it includes a beautiful crash) every time a Timer calls this function:

`func updateTime() {`

```
    let currentTime = Int(player.currentTime)

    let minutes = currentTime/60
    let seconds = currentTime - minutes * 60

    if seconds < 10 {

        tempo.text = String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds)

    } else {

        tempo.text = String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds)

    }

    durationSliderOutlet.value = Float(player.currentTime)

    if currentTime == Int(player.duration - 1) {

        playpauseOutlet.setTitle("Play", for: .normal)
        isPlaying = false

    }

    print("currentTime: \(currentTime)")
    print(Int(player.duration))
    print("minutes: \(minutes)")
    print("seconds: \(seconds)")
    print(isPlaying)

}
```

I'm just trying to display the current time of an audio file in a label, and if I comment out this code

```
if seconds < 10 {

    tempo.text = String(minutes) + ":0" + String(seconds)

} else {

    tempo.text = String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds)

}
```

...everything works just fine!

The second one throws the same crash and error when I press a button...

```
 @IBAction func playpauseButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if isPlaying == false {

        playpauseOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "pause.png"), for: .normal)
        player.play()
        isPlaying = true


    } else {

        playpauseOutlet.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play.png"), for: .normal)
        player.pause()
        isPlaying = false


    }
}
```

Note: `(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "play.png")` appears as a little white rectangle. And if I try something like `playpauseOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: .normal)` it also crashes.

What I'm pretending to do with this code is to change the "play" image of a button to "pause" image or vice versa depending of the isPlaying state. Thank in advance!

Comment: This kind of crash usually happens when you have a miss connection in your interface builder. By your comment that trying `playpauseOutlet.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: .normal)` it crashes I would double check the IB connection of this UIButton

Comment: You know what? I was sure that I connected everything properly, but I checked again and I found that tempo label and playpauseOutlet weren't connected at all. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad to help. It happens all the time